# How can we pass the parameter values from Jenkins job to pom.xml and then to my system property in JAVA code?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

My question may look a little easy to answer but I couldn't really work it out.

I am working on a project where I have configured the Jenkins job for my build.

What i have done so far is that I have made a maven job which has the pom.xml path configured and with two goals 'clean test' . When I run it it works just fine.

Now I wanna pass the Paramter value `BROWSER` from Jenkins which may have value like Firefox, Chrome and i want it to pass to java code so that specific browser may open.

I have used the system property in my code:

`protected static final String BROWSER = System.getProperty("BROWSER","chrome");`

Now I want to pass the value from jenkins to pom and then java code.

Here is my pom which is faulty:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.18.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <BROWSER>${env.BROWSER}</BROWSER>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

But here it gives me error like `cannot resolve symbol env.BROWSER`

WorkAround:
As a workaround I have made the command in Jenkins goals look like this:

```
clean test -DREMOTE_DRIVER=${REMOTE_DRIVER} -DSELENIUM_HOST=${SELENIUM_HOST} -DBROWSER=${BROWSER}
```

But I think its not the ideal way of doing it.

I have already made the parameters in my Jenkins build Parameter Name - "BROWSER" with choices of 'firefox' 'chrome' and 'ie'.

Now i wana just call it in pom ( i used ${env.BROWSER} ) and then pass to my system property in java code. (It is not working for me)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Environmental properties in jenkins are not the system properties of JVM. To set the properties either you need to set it using commandline.
`export BROWSER =chrome` 
or 
you can set it in `This build is parameterized` section of your jenkins build configuration.

Comment: May be I wasnt clear in my question. Sorry for that but I have already made parameters in my Build. Like with name BROWSER with 3 choices "chrome" , "firefox" and "ie". Now I wana pass this from jenkins to pom and from pom to system properties in my java code.

Comment: When you check `This build is parameterized` then you will be able to add parameters to the build where jenkins will replace any token before build. Let say you have `BROWSER` parameter set in jenkins configuration then you can use `%BROWSER%` in your pom where you need to set the browser. You can set a default value, or you can parse the value `-DBROWSER=chrome` where you configure jenkins on build command. Eg. `mvn clean install -DBROWSER=chrome`

Comment: Hi Eranda, Thanks a lot for your answer. But if I configure my pom like this<configuration>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <BROWSER>**%BROWSER%**</BROWSER>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>  this does not work . My jenkins job has a parameter with name "BROWSER 
" but the value is not passed.  However if in place of "%BROWSER%" in pom i use firefox it works fine.